# PHP Active Record Update Relation Table

Tags: php, activerecord, phpactiverecord

This is my many to many relation

```
class Post extends ActiveRecord\Model {
    static $table_name = 'app_post';

    static $has_many = array(
        array('postcategory'),
        array('category', 'through' => 'postcategory')
    );
}

class Category extends ActiveRecord\Model {
    static $table_name = 'app_post_category';

    static $has_many = array(
        array('post', 'through' => 'postcategory'),
        array('postcategory')
    );
}

class PostCategory extends ActiveRecord\Model {
    static $table_name = 'app_post_category_relation';

    static $belongs_to = array(
        array('post'),
        array('category')
    );
}
```

To create new record in post i use

```
$post = Post::create(
    array(
        'title' => 'Title', 
        'description' => 'Description', 
        'keyword' => 'key,word'
    )
);

$post->create_postcategory(array('category_id' => '1'));
$post->create_postcategory(array('category_id' => '3'));
```

But i dont know how to update this record ?

```
$post = Post::find(1);
$post->title = 'Some title';
$post->save();
```

It's just update post table how about relation table ?